# How to configure android settings from Windows/Linux

Tags: settings

Let say i need to enforce some configuration into 100 same android devices, speaking: enable wifi with some config, disable NFC, Allow NonGoogle Play apps and few more.

How it can be done? (there are some approaches to install APK via cable and Android SDK).
My idea is ho write XML, attach mobile to PC, hit the button and it will be done.

Is it possible some how?

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps utilize [SL4A](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) and create a script or scripts to handle the settings?